# Running “import tensorflow” on Mac generates "No module named tensorflow" error

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

Actually I already installed tensorflow by using

```
$ pip install tensorflow
```

and it works well when I use

```
$ python
Python 2.7.15 (default, Jul 23 2018, 21:27:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import tensorflow
>>>
```

but when I use python3 on command line

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
>>>
```

it shows an error, and it shows the same error when I use IDLE

Comment: For python3, do pip3 install tensorflow

Comment: `pip3 install tensorflow`

Comment: well it seems that I should use $ pip3 install tensorflow, but there's another problem of my pip3, let me try to solve that problem first......

Comment: Python 3.7 is not supported yet, check out this thread, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337939/cant-install-tensorflow-mac]

Comment: You've probably got the following error with "pip3 install tensorflow" command, 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )' - again this version of Python is not supported

Answer (score 1):

use

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

pip installs to default python directory. pip3 installs to python3