# Mac using:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Tags: python, macos, pip

python version:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.0
```

pip3 path:

```
which -a pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

pip3 version:

```
pip3 -V
pip 18.0 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

the tensorflow could be installed by pip without any problem but couldn't be installed by pip3

```
$ pip3 install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

the similar problem happens when I try to install any other packages.

Comment: Have you tried with creating a separate virtual environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Tensorflow Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337939/cant-install-tensorflow-mac)

Comment: Tensorflow doesn't support Python 3.7 yet. Use Python 3.6 for now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by uninstalling python@2 and reinstall python@3.8

```sh
$ brew doctor
# it shows a lot warnings about python@2 and python@3.8

$ brew uninstall python@2

$ brew reinstall python@3.8

$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.6

$ pip3 install tensorflow
```