# How to correctly install TensorFlow using pip?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install TensorFlow via pip3 on my Mac. Whenever I run the command `pip3 install tensorflow` or `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` I receive the same error...

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
```

No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Python version: 3.7.0

Pip version: 18.1

Is there another way I could go about installing?

Comment: have you tried just `pip install tensorflow`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Tensorflow Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337939/cant-install-tensorflow-mac)

Comment: Tensorflow doesn't support python 3.7 yet, need to use python 3.6 or anaconda as suggested in the answers.

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you using 'notebook'?
'Anaconda' and 'notebook' are best to work with python and ML packages. You shouldn't have trouble with conda.

Try just "pip install tensorflow"