# Mac OS High Sierra: Tensorflow verions returned by `pip3 upgrade ` and `python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'` differ

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I am currently getting the error, `TypeError: softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`.

It seems this error is common if you don't have up-to-date keras/tensorflow.

I checked what version of tensorflow I have with `python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'` It returned `0.12.0` which indeed looks out of date.

However, when I try to upgrade tensorflow, with `pip3 install tensorflow --upgrade` I get

> Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   (0.12.0) Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade:
>   numpy>=1.11.0 in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages(from
>   tensorflow) (1.15.3) Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade:
>   protobuf==3.1.0 in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   (from tensorflow) (3.1.0) Requirement already satisfied, skipping
>   upgrade: six>=1.10.0 in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   (from tensorflow) (1.11.0) Requirement already satisfied, skipping
>   upgrade: wheel>=0.26 in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   (from tensorflow) (0.32.2) Requirement already satisfied, skipping
>   upgrade: setuptools in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   (from protobuf==3.1.0->tensorflow) (39.0.1)

I tried to force the update with `pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow` but got:

> Collecting tensorflow   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution
>   found for tensorflow

When I tried to upgrade with `python3 -m pip install tensorflow --upgrade`:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel>=0.26 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.32.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf==3.1.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.11.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages(from tensorflow) (1.15.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.10.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from protobuf==3.1.0->tensorflow) (39.0.1)
```

When I print sys.path in my program, I get:

```
['/Users/myname/topdirect', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

`pip3 show tensorflow` I get:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 0.12.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: six, protobuf, numpy, wheel
Required-by:
```

Comment: Did you install tensorflow with pip3 or in some other way? These error probably mean that you have more than one place where Python libraries go. Try printing sys.path from python3 and check if it corresponds to where pip3 installs go.

Comment: Always use `python3 -m pip`, the `pip3` script may have a different environment.

Comment: @o11c use `python3 -m pip` in place of what? which line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Tensorflow Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337939/cant-install-tensorflow-mac)

Comment: Tensorflow>1.0 doesn't work with Python 3.7 yet. Either switch to Python 3.6, or stick with the 0.12 for the moment being.

Comment: @Matt I am running into this same issue - any luck with it in the last 2 weeks?!?!?!

Comment: @Canovice I ended up installing Anaconda and then installing tensorflow through anaconda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend using anaconda  environment to manage your tensorflow version. On the other side, you need to add your operating system to make the question more clear.

Comment: updated the question with my os. do you have more information about how i would use anaconda to resolve my problem? perhaps tests for me to try? or a way to upgrade tensorflow using anaconda?

Comment: Oh...for Mac...if you do want to use GPU for acceleration, I think anaconda is good.