# Installing Older Tensorflow on Windows (.whl file)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I've been trying to install tensorflow 1.0.1 in a variety of ways with no luck. Currently using Python 3.7 on Windows 10 (64 bit platform). I have plenty of CPU and memory power, but essentially little gpu power (using a server). My best bet was to use install an older tf version through a .whl file (in virtualenv), but keep getting an error. I download this while in the directory of the file:

```
pip install tensorflow-1.3.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

but keep getting-

```
tensorflow-1.3.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I prefer to continue using tf through Windows and CPython.... unless there's no other way

Comment: TensorFlow does not yet support Python 3.7, the "cp35" in the whl file name means it was compiled for python 3.5, please try using that version.

Comment: [Tensorflow is not available for Python 3.7 yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51463905/2650249). There is [an unofficial 1.9.0 wheel for 3.7 & windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow), you can try that out in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'cp37' whl file instead of'pip install tensorflow-1.3.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl'

cp35 is meant to be installed on Python 3.5.

But i think 1.3.0 only support up to Python 3.6 (https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.3.0/#files)

Hope this helps, I'm also new to this and please correct me if I'm wrong.

Cheers