# Pip is not installing TensorFlow Nightly Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, pip

Pip is not installing TensorFlow Nightly. Is there another way I can install it? Here is what I tried.

```
Louis-MacBook-Pro:~ yelouis$ python3 -m pip install tf-nightly
Collecting tf-nightly
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tf-nightly (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tf-nightly

Louis-MacBook-Pro:~ yelouis$ pip install tf-nightly
Collecting tf-nightly
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tf-nightly (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tf-nightly
```

[image: terminal]

Update: I have downloaded the file and trying to use the path to have pip install it. Here are the results and it is still not working.

[image: terminal2]

Comment: if you are also using anaconda in your system, then you  can also  install it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Tensorflow Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337939/cant-install-tensorflow-mac)

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading tf-nightly from [here](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/#files), then install using `pip install <path/to/package>.whl`.

Make sure you download the one that is compatible with your Python version.

Comment: I am getting that tf_nightly-1.13.0a0.dev20181218-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_12_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform as the result of entering that command. @Chris M.

Comment: @LouisYe Looks like you're using Python 3, in which case I think you should try downloading the other file (tf_nightly-1.13.0a0.dev20181218-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl).

Comment: The other file isn't working either. I get the same errors.

Comment: Does Python 3.7.1 not download the 36 wheel? I think that is the problem.

Comment: @LouisYe Try creating a virtual environment with Python 3.6 using `conda create -n my_environment_name python=3.6` then try installing tf-nightly in that environment.

Comment: I was using Python 3.7 but I could not see cp37 (build for Python 3.7) here https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files
Therefore I installed Python 3.6 also and created new virtual environment as recommended by @markos with Python 3.6 and everything is fine now.