# Can't install Tensorflow with wheel file

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install tensorflow. I have python 3.6.4 and am running Windows 10 64bit.

First I tried these two methods:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

But I got the error:

```
Collecting tensorflow 
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Then I tried to use the wheel file to install tensorflow. I saved the wheel file in the same folder as python 3.6. The wheel file I used was:

```
tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

And I got the error:

```
tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I looked at the tensorflow installation [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3) and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

P.S. I also have python 2.7 installed. I use `'python'` and `'pip'` for python 2.
And I use `'py'` and `'pip3'` for python 3.

Comment: Try to update pip ‘pip install -U pip’

Comment: first question is what OS are you on

Comment: Try python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: Or try to use anaconda

Comment: What is the output of `pip3 --version` and `py -3.6 -c "from setuptools import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_supported()[0])"`?

Comment: @HaidarZeineddine my pip3 version is 19.0.1.

Comment: @gameon67 That looks like a file for the mac OS.

Comment: @hoefling My pip3 version is 19.0.1. The other outputs are cp36, cp36m and win32

Comment: You have a 32bit distribution of Python installed (the rest matches fine). `tensorflow` can be installed only for 64bit Python distribution. Uninstall yours, download the [installer for `win_amd64`](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/python-3.6.8-amd64.exe) and install from it. Then rerun `pip3 install tensorflow`, it will work just fine.

Comment: @hoefling Thank, I'll give it a try

Comment: @hoefling Would `tensorflow` be compatible with python 3.7 or should I get the latest version of 3.6?

Comment: `tensorflow` doesn't support Python 3.7 yet. You can track the progress in [issue #20517](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517); see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51463905/2650249) for more details.

Comment: For Windows, you can try out the experimental 1.9.0 wheel that can be installed with Python 3.7; download it [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow). IIRC, it's a CPU-only wheel (no CUDA), so if you don't need GPU support, it should work.